# getting rid of dialog box when android phone connected

Tags: usb, mount, android, automount

Since upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04, whenever I connect my Android Galaxy SII to my laptop via USB to charge, I get a dialog box that says

```
  Unable to mount SAMSUNG Android
  Unable to open MTP device '[usb:002,021]'
```

If I want to mount it, I select the mounting option on the phone as usual, and it mounts fine as a USB mass storage device.  I don't know why Ubuntu is trying to mount the device before it switches to USB mass storage mode.

Is there a way to disable this automounting, or at least to disable the dialog boxes when it fails?  (I still want other USB devices to be mounted when inserted, as usual.)  In other words, I want the sane 12.04 behaviour back.

Comment: You can answer yourself now? I suffer from the same problem, also S2.

Comment: No, I haven't been able to solve this yet.  I happens every time I plug my phone in to charge, which is annoying...

Answer (score 0):

1. Install dconf-editor.
2. Go to org -> gnome -> desktop -> media-handling
3. Uncheck automount_open

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, since I still want other devices to mount automatically.  I just don't want to see the MTP error dialogs.